# Does adding a polynomial-time function impact APX-hardness?

Tags: complexity-theory

I have two optimization problems $A$ and $B$, and I recently managed to show that there exist functions $f$ and $g$ that are computable in polynomial time, such that for any instance $x$ of $A$ there holds
$$OPT_A(x) + g(x) = OPT_B(f(x)).$$

I know that $A$ is NP-hard, which implies that $B$ must be NP-hard as well. However, how about APX-hardness? Can I say anything about the (in)approximability of $B$ assuming that $A$ is APX-hard, or does the $+g(x)$ mess everything up, and nothing can be concluded?

I don't have a very good intuition for approximability-preserving reductions, so I tried to prove it by arguing that, if there were an approximation algorithm for $B$ with arbitrarily small ratio $C$, then there must also be one for $A$; this would contradict the APX-hardness of $A$, and thus $B$ must be APX-hard.
However, the presence of this $+g(x)$ invalidates this argument, and I'm not sure how to get around that...

Comment: I doubt it.  Consider a case where $g(x)$ is always/often/sometimes much larger than $OPT_B(f(x))$.  Then an approximation ratio for $OPT_B(f(x))$ doesn't translate into any useful approximation ratio for $OPT_A(x)$.